# RadioButton TwoWay Binding Issues

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

Consider the below simplified application, which allows you to select between two elements, each of which has A and B boolean properties that are bound to radio buttons.  The idea is that you should be able to set A/B independently for each element and if you switch between elements, the radio buttons should reflect the flags for that element.  This isn't what happens however.

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace SandboxWpf
{
    public sealed class Element : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _memberA;

        public bool MemberA
        {
            get { return _memberA; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _memberA)
                {
                    _memberA = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();                    
                }
            }
        }

        private bool _memberB;
        public bool MemberB
        {
            get { return _memberB; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _memberB)
                {
                    _memberB = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();                    
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public sealed class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private readonly List<Element> _elements;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            _elements = new List<Element>();
            _elements.Add(new Element());
            _elements.Add(new Element());
        }

        public IEnumerable<Element> Elements
        {
            get { return _elements; }
        }

        private Element _selectedElement;

        public Element SelectedElement
        {
            get { return _selectedElement; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _selectedElement)
                {
                    _selectedElement = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Window XAML (no code behind):

```
<Window x:Class="SandboxWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:SandboxWpf="clr-namespace:SandboxWpf"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <SandboxWpf:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElement, Mode=TwoWay}" />

        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedElement}">
            <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SandboxWpf:Element}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <RadioButton Content="A" IsChecked="{Binding MemberA, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <RadioButton Content="B" IsChecked="{Binding MemberB, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentPresenter.Resources>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

You can switch the A and B values using the radio buttons on each element.  However, if you set the first element and second element to different values (one A and one B), then go back to the other selected element, the other element will now have both A and B set to false.  Something wonky is happening when the SelectedElement property changes on the ContentPresenter that somehow triggers the TwoWay binding I think, causing it to overwrite the property values, but I can't figure out why this would happen or how to resolve it.  This is a deliberately simplified version of something I'm seeing in a larger application.

Any idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they belong to same Group, see [GroupName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton.groupname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can set individual GroupName for each Element(every element has different group).

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SandboxWpf:Element}">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding ElementGroupName}" Content="A" IsChecked="{Binding MemberA, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
          <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding ElementGroupName}" Content="B" IsChecked="{Binding MemberB, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
      </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: This does resolve the issue if I explicitly clear the other flag in my handler for the property setter.  It's a bit awkward, though; the default behavior of grouped radio buttons clearing other bound flags is kinda nice.  It just appears to have an odd behavior in this particular case (the clearing is somehow applying to a stale version of the binding that has not had its data context reset yet?)

Comment: yes,it's a bit awkward, it's more make scene that use a custom control inherit togglebutton and re-write its style(looks like radiobutton but do not have group ability)